# Wechat sandbox unable to configure setting url and token

Tags: wechat

I am trying to setup Wechat's sandbox account and I am following [this site](http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/building-a-wechat-weixin-robot/).

I am pointing the URL to my site and I've tried different settings for the Token. However, I am unable to press submit because I see this weird "Unable to configure" error without any explanation whatsoever.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: OP: did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 4):

When you save your configuration, WeChat will try to send you a GET with an `echostr` query string. You must respond to that request with the content of that `echostr` value.

Here's an example in Node.js:

```
express.Router().get('/wechat', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.query.echostr);
}
```

More information here: http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Getting_Started

It is also possible that WeChat is just acting up, just keep trying to save until it works if you are sure that your webhook is correctly responding the `echostr`.

Obviously, you will need to handle the signature to make it secure and not listen to any requests that isn't coming from WeChat. Your shared token will be used to generate the signature. You must generate the same signature on your side and make sure it matches.

Signature validation is explained in Step 2 of the link mentioned earlier.

Answer (score -4):

Your token is very short

you can generate token with appID and with secret using POSTMAN with link below

https://api.wechat.com/cgi-bin/token?grant_type=client_credential&appid=sandbox_test_account_app_id&secret=sandbox_test_account_secret

Comment: The token isn't the access token generated by WeChat. This token is the secret shared between WeChat and your webhook. It can be anything.